# Blazor virtualization with row grouping

Tags: html, blazor

Im creating a grouped list with sticky header. Really would like to use virtualization with it. But the virtualization doesnt work when i set fixed height and overflow on the top level `table-content-container`. Virtualization only works when fixed height and overflow is set to `group-body-container`.

Here's the html i got what does not work:

```
<div class="table-container">
    <div class="table-header grid-row-template">
        <div class="header-item">Id</div>
        <div class="header-item">Name</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="table-content-container" style="height:50vh; overflow-y:scroll">
    @foreach (DataGroup group in dataGroups)
    {
        <div class="group-header">
            <MudToggleIconButton
                @bind-Toggled="@group.IsExpanded"
                Icon="@Icons.Filled.ExpandMore"
                Color="Color.Secondary"
                ToggledIcon="@Icons.Filled.ExpandLess"                
                Size="Size.Small"
                ToggledSize="Size.Small"/>
            <MudText Color="@Color.Primary">@group.GroupName</MudText>    
        </div>
        @if (group.IsExpanded)
        {
            <div class="group-body-container">
                <Virtualize Items="group.DataRow" Context="row" ItemSize="20">
                    <div class="grid-row-template data-row">
                        <div class="data-item">@row.Id</div>
                        <div class="data-item">@row.Name</div>
                    </div>
                </Virtualize>
            </div>
        }
    }
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the virtualization works: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GEcwagOjgXcmYqFL

Here its not working: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GawcYUuNUXbCiTTY

The goal would be to have the virtualization working with the second example, when scrolled only the top header would be "sticky".

**EDIT**:
Here's recording of what i would like to achieve but with working virtualization (https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GawcYUuNUXbCiTTY):
[image]

Is this even possible with blazors virtualization component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the Virtualize component needs a limiting height - either explicit or implicit. As you have it now, each Virtualize can just grow to consume as much space as it needs.

You can make your container use flexbox and your group container have a min/max height of 100% to achieve this:

```
.table-content-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap:0;
}

.group-body-container {
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Updated demo #2 where the expanded group matches the container height - but without more information about what you are trying to do this could go on forever....:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wOQwEKbUdhZHlbiE

To round things off - I do not recommend this design, but to show it is possible, you can also hide the scrollbars on the expanded/virtualised groups with CSS

```css
.group-body-container {
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.group-body-container {
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
.group-body-container::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none;  /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Here is a demo: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cammugcNEmPoITgg - with a scrollbar only on the main container, so you can only scroll the virtualized groups contents with mousewheel/touch - which is why I don't like it.

Comment: Your solution works, but its not the what i am after. It makes it work just like it was working in the 1st example where the scrollbar is inside the group. I would like to keep the scrollbar on the outer container (Just like in the second example) but also get the virtualization working when inside the groups.

Comment: In my demo, virtualization is working for each group and the outer container has a scrollbar. You will need to explain more clearly what it is you are trying to achieve, because I don't see what is not working here.

Comment: I added a recording to my original post what shows what i would like to get working with working virtualization. Question is is it even possible.

Comment: Looking at your recording, there is no virtualisation at all - I'm afraid it is still not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, that is the exactly what i am trying to achieve, virtualization while the overflow and scrollbar is on `table-content-container` element.

Comment: So, when you expand one group, how big do you want it to grow to?

Comment: When i expand one group i would like it to grow as big as the `table-content-container` div.

Comment: What happens to the other groups when it expands?

Comment: Just like in the recording, the other items just get pushed down, and only way to get to them is to scroll.

Comment: So, that is exactly what my demo #2 above does - is that what you want?

Comment: Yes and no, your demo has 2 scrollbars, i wanted to get away with just one.

Comment: But you want the groups to be virtualized (i.e. they need a scrollbar so the user can scroll them) inside a container that also scrolls - your design is sounding impossible to use